# How to run the .html file in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, intellij-idea

I have just wrote a javascript file which I ran the via intelliJ using a few different browsers e.g. Google Chrome. This works fine as it runs locally e.g. http://localhost:**//**.

However I want to be able to send it to someone so they just click on the .html file (packaged in correct folder) and it appears on their browser. Is there anyway I can do this? Right now the url points locally e.g. file:///Users/**/project/file.html.

Comment: Show a full HTML tag that is using one of the HREFs.  "Right now the url points locally e.g. file:///Users/**/project/file.html." Do you mean it has the absolute path from your own machine, or the absolute local path of the target user's machine?  If the 2nd, then isn't that exactly what you want?  You want them to just open it from the local folder and link to other files relative in the same local folder.

Answer (score 3):

Use a relative path. If your HTML file is in the same folder as the JS file, this means simply including it like so:

`<script src="jsfile.js"></script>`

If it's in a subdirectory, include all the folders necessary to get there:

`<script src="subdirectory1/subdirectory2/jsfile.js"></script>`

If it's up a directory, use the `..` path:

`<script src="../anotherfolder/jsfile.js"></script>`

Or just include it in the HTML page itself:

```
<script>
  // your code here
</script>
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. It's in the same folder and I had already included <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> in the body of the html